# Twilio SIP Trunking - RFC 3966 (tel uri)

Tags: twilio, sip

I have configured SIP trunking in twillio. It is working partially. Here is the scenario--

Uesr dials the number cfgd in Twillio and the INVITE goes to our SIP AS via Originating trunk. Our SIP AS sends back 302(Moved temporarily) to Twillio with Contact header (`Contact: <tel:+1xxx-yyy-zzzz>`) configured as teluri. The phone number in teluri is also one of the twillio's number.

Somehow Twilio didn't process 302 request from our SIP AS. Does Twillio supports RFC 3966 for tel uri? Appreciate any response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid Twilio doesn't currently support 302 responses in SIP. It looks as though you've had a similar response from our support team and there is an open feature request to enable this in the future, but for now it's best to avoid redirects if possible.